# using primitive types along generics+interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

The best way I found explaining my question is through following example.
For this, lets suppose the following class:

```
public class Class1<C> where C : IInterface<C> 
{ 
   // some properties 
}
```

Now I define the interface as:

```
public interface IInterface<C>
{
   char CompareTo(C that);
   C defaultValue { set; get; }
}
```

Now I wanna use `Class1` with a primitive type (e.g.,`int`) as:

```
Class1<int> myClass = new Class1<int>();
```

However, this is abuse cos I **can't** use type `int` as type parameter in generics.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want to add a generic constraint then somehow ignore it?

Comment: You can't use `int`, because `int` doesn't implement your interface, and you explicitly constrained the type parameter to those that do. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually my intention was to use kinda boxing similar to Oriani's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added a [`constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) in the `Class1<C>` defiing the `C` generic type must implement `IInterface<C>`. The reason is the `int` does not implement the `IInterface<C>` so you cannot construct `Class1<int>`. In this case, you make a constraint into the `C` generic type be a specifique type like `class`, `struct`, etc. and make your Class1<> implement the interface generically, for sample:

```
public class Class1<C> : IInterface<C>
    where C : struct
{
    public char CompareTo(C that)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public C defaultValue { get; set; }
}

public interface IInterface<C> where C : struct
{
    char CompareTo(C that);
    C defaultValue { set; get; }
}
```

And use it.

```
Class1<int> c = new Class1<int>();
```

When you add a constraint like this, you just limit what your generic type `C` can be. In this case, just `value-type` like `int`, `double`, `bool`, etc.. can be used in generic, but it is not necessary. You can remove if you need and keep just a generic type. It will be handled as an `object`.

Comment: Thanks; Actually I already tried this, but it gives me following error: "The type `Custom` cannot be used as type parameter `C` in the generic type or method `Class1<C>`. There is not implicit reference conversion from `Custom` to `IInterface<Custom>`"

Comment: @Oriani; thanks this answers my question ... however, I don't understand why should I have a constraint like `where C : struct` ?!

Comment: When you add a constraint like this, you just limit what your generic type `C` can be. In this case, just value-types can be used in generic, but it is not necessary. You can remove if you need.

Comment: this complements everything. 10x ;-)

Comment: I complement the anwser :)